# effect of temperature on position of equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

I was wondering if there was an intuitive way of explaining how a change in temperature would effect the position of an equilibrium, without using le chateliers principle. Le Chateliers principle doesn't seem to explain why the equilibrium shifts the way it does, I was wondering if there was a way of explaining this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange. Have a look at the FAQ to learn how to post good questions, and hopefully get good answers. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Well, For endothermic reaction the Number of moles at the product side increase with increase in temperature. 
And for exothermic, it decreases with Increase in temperature.. 
And exactly vice versa with respect to the reactant side.. 
It is in Accordance with the Le chaitliers Principle..